# How to map array of objects to key-values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In JS, I have an array `A = [{k:"a",v:3},{k:"b",v:4}]` consisting of objects, defining key-values. I want to generate array `B`:

```
let B = 
((A)=>{
    let B=[];
    for(let i of A)
        B[i.k]=i.v;
    return B;
})(A);
```

So that it maps `A`'s object keys `k` to `B`'s keys, and values `v` to its values.
Is that achievable more easily, through Array mapreduce functions? Could you help me with correct syntax? SO that B (for our example) would be:

```
let B = [];
B["a"]=3;
B["b"]=4;
console.log( B );
[ a: 3, b: 4 ]
```

Comment: expected output is not clear. Can you please share expected output

Comment: @brk > [ a: 3, b: 4 ]

Comment: expected output in this format `[ a: 3, b: 4 ]` is wrong,array cannot have value like this unless it is array of string. Are you looking for`[{ a: 3},{ b: 4}]`

Comment: If you are searching for a final structure that maps each `key` to the related `value`, forget about array. Instead use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an `object`.

Comment: @brk Sorry I dont know how is this called, but this result should be possible produce on node.js and in browser console, despite of naming scheme. Result is simple, please dont dig too deep. Just how to rewrite code with mapreduce?

Comment: [Don't abuse arrays](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), use an object for a key-value map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the IIFE and use

```
const B = {};
for (const {k, v} of A)
    B[k] = v;
```

A `reduce` solution is also possible, but less concise:

```
const B = A.reduce((acc, {k, v}) => {
    acc[k] = v;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thank you, I would not abuse arrays. Just wanted to see possible implementation with reduce! (I knew its possible just forgot how)

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with mapped arrays for a key/value pair.

```js
var array = [{ k: "a", v: 3 }, { k: "b", v: 4 }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ k, v }) => [k, v]));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Also nice approach! Thanks for your input.